# Нужно ли локализовать иконку ответа?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, мобильная-версия

В мобильной версии сайта (которой мало кто пользуется) есть иконка ответа:

[image: Иконка ответа]

Нужно ли её локализовать? Пока что я не видел (если не брать в расчет основную эмблему) локализаций картинок. Только текст на transifex.

Comment: Ноль Атветов...

Comment: @NickVolynkin возможно `О` будет путаться с нулём. Тем не менее, в поиске (обычном) у нас выводятся `В` и `О` для вопросов и ответов соответственно.

Comment: @alexolut вапроз/атвед

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `Qапроз` тогда уж

Answer (score 4):

**Удалить букву А** из значка вообще.

Таким образом сам значок комментария белого цвета будет говорить о том, что ответы есть, а значок комментария зелёного (или какого-то другого) цвета будет говорить о том, что есть принятый ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Сделать перевод для значка **нужно**.

Comment: Глупо конечно, но автор общего вопроса/ответа голосовать не может. Сообщение как бы общее, да не совсем.

Comment: об этом уже есть [вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3600/176217).

Answer (score 1):

Сделать более международно-понятный вариант, разместив внутри "speech bubble" символ `i`.

Comment: Значок вопроса - это который на представленной картинке?

Comment: @alexolut нет, там именно значок ответа, а где встречаются оба, я сходу не помню, в поиске что ли...

Comment: В каком таком поиске? Напомню, тут пока речь про мобильную версию сайта. В полнофункциональной вообще буквы без картинок (что несколько странно вообще-то).

Comment: @alexolut без картинок? Э-эм-м, нет, я немного не о том, пофиксил ответ. А где видел картинку вопроса, сейчас поищу. Просто подозреваю, что значки там одни и те же.

Comment: Ну вот, например, [результат поиска](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0): для вопросов буква `В`, для ответов `О`. Никаких картинок.

Comment: @alexolut вообще-то есть :) У вопросов слева счётчик ответов к ним. Но это уже не по теме вопроса. Пофиксил ответ в полном соответствии с вопросом.

Comment: зеленый квадратик залитый или пустой, об этом что ли речь?

Comment: @alexolut да нет же, про то, что в вопросе. На скриншоте. Туда стрелочка ещё указывает.

Comment: Так это значок ответа, а не вопроса.

Comment: @alexolut значок **у** вопроса **про** ответы. Всё сложно.

Answer (score -1):

Сделать перевод для значка **не нужно**. Оставить как есть.