# Русифицированные иконки для вопросов и ответов

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, локализация, дизайн

Неожиданно заметил, что вместо иконок `Q`и `A` для вопросов и ответов соответственно на сайте теперь используются русскоязычные варианты `В` и `О`:

> [image: Лучшие сообщения]

Можно посмотреть в [профиле](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/?tab=profile) в секции лучших сообщений.

Почему-то об этом не было никакого маломальского анонса (если что будем считать таковым текущий вопрос).

Это изменение затронуло и другие не-английские версии Stack Overflow, но почему-то не японскую, где до сих пор присутствуют англоязычные иконки Q/A:

> [image: jaSO]

При этом у меня есть [старый вопрос о подобной иконке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3949/176217), но для мобильной версии сайта. И там всё ещё по-прежнему присутствует латинская буква `A`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Оказалось, что на MSE бывшим нашим модератором был задан соответствующий вопрос [Allow localizing the "Q" and "A" icons in the user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347163/339911) и 15 октября (условно пару недель назад) получен и принят ответ о том, что иконки для неанглоязычных сайтов были добавлены. А тут на ruSO отписаться не захотел никто.

Comment: `<...>but we're looking into whether we can condense the translations into single characters there as well.<...>`

Comment: @VictorVosMottor что вы хотели этим сказать?

Comment: Это изменение затронуло и другие не-английские версии Stack Overflow, но **почему-то не японскую**, где до сих пор присутствуют англоязычные иконки Q/A — почему

Comment: @VictorVosMottor да, это я заметил. Такое ощущение, что сами японцы не знают, есть ли у них отдельный иероглиф для обозначения ответа/вопроса, чтобы можно было из него сформировать иконку подходящую.